# Insert large amount of entries into Mongodb with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, database

So I have a file that contains "pins" which I need to input into mongodb. THey are contained in a file called `pins.txt` and the data is new line delimited:

```
A4DS24SD2
DF234SDF2
HFFGHFG45
JDRSDFG35
...
```

There are about 70,000 pins that I need to import.

Each pin also has a default `used` status of `false`

So, to import such a huge number of pins, I've cooked this up using nodejs/mongoose (which my app is built in)

```
  fs.readFile './data/pins-test.txt', 'utf8', (err,data)->
    if err
      console.log err
    codes = data.split('\n')
    codes.forEach (code)->
      pin = new Pin()
      pin.pinid = code
      pin.save()
```

Works great with a testing of a few hundred pins, but my machine runs out of memory when I try the 70,000 file giving the error:

`FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_2 Allocation failed - process out of memory`

So, my question is, what is the best way to import this much data? Should I be using async.js to do these one at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `fs.readFile` is that the whole file is loaded before the callback is fired.

You could use [BufferedReader](https://github.com/Gagle/Node-BufferedReader) to do this line by line

Something like this should work (note... untested!)

```
reader = require "buffered-reader"
DataReader = reader.DataReader
```

...

```
  new DataReader("./data/pins1.txt", { encoding: "utf8" })
    .on "error", (error)->
        console.log ("error: " + error);
    .on "line", (line)->
        console.log(i,line)
        i++
        pin = new Pin()
        pin.pinid = line
        pin.save()
    .on "end", ()->
        console.log ("EOF")
    .read()
```

Comment: Wow, turns out my file is 700,000 lines, not 70,000 lines. Needless to say, this module is worked great. Imported everying in just a few minutes. I've updated your code example for my working code.

Comment: I was going to say 70k lines didn't sound long enough to fill your RAM!
 Glad it helped.